# will gatling actually perform the operation or will it check only the urls' response time?

Tags: gatling

I have a gatling test for an application that will answer a survey and upon answering this survey, the application will identify possible answers that may pose a risk and create what we call riskareas. These riskareas are normally created in the background as soon as the survey answering is finished. My question is I have a gatling test with ten users who will go and answer the survey and logout, I used recorder to record the test; now after these ten users are finished I do not see any riskareas being created in the application. Am I missing something--should the survey be really answered by gatling (like it does in selenium) user or is it just the urls that the gatling test will touch ?

I am new to gatling please help.

Answer (score 1):

Gatling *should* be indistinguishable from a user in a web browser (or Selenium) as far as the server is concerned, so the end result should be exactly the same as if you'd gone through the process yourself. However, writing a Gatling script is a little more work than writing a Selenium script.

For performance reasons, Gatling operates at a lower level than Selenium. Gatling works with the actual data that is sent and received from the server (i.e, the actual GETs and POSTs sent to the server), rather than with user-level interactions (such as clicking links and filling forms).

The recorder will generally produce a relaitvely "dumb" script. It records the exact data that was sent to the server, and makes no attempt to account for things that may change from run to run. For example, the web application you are testing might have hidden form fields that contain session information, or the link addresses might contain a unique identifier or a session id.

This means that your script may not be doing what you think it's doing.

To debug the script, the first thing to do is to [add checks on each of the requests](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.2/http/http_check.html), to validate that you are getting the response you expect (for example, check that when you submit page 1 of the survey, you are taken to page 2 - check for something that you'd only expect to find on page 2, like a specific question).

Once you know which requests are failing, look at what data was sent with the request, and try to figure out where it came from. You will probably find that there are session ids, view state, or similar, that must be extracted from the previous page.

It will help to enable request and response logging, [as per the documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.2/general/configuration.html).

To simplify testing of web apps, we wrote [some helper functions](https://github.com/clickscript/clickscript) to allow tests to be written in a more Selenium-like way. Once you understand what your application is doing, you may find that it simplifies scripting for you too. However, understanding why your current script doesn't work the way you expect should be your first step.